# What does calendar.js do?

Tags: javascript, phtml, calendar

I am trying to cut some code to speed up the site and found aclendar.phtml + js and just wondering, what do they do?

My site's home page does not have any of calendar code but if you were to open inner pages, like https://www.airyhair.com/tape-in-hair-extensions.html

it has this:

```
'DHTML Date/Time Selector\n' +
"(c) dynarch.com 2002-2005 / Author: Mihai Bazon\n" +
'For latest version visit: http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/\n' +
'Distributed under GNU LGPL. See http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html for details.' +
'\n\n' +
'Date selection:\n' +
'- Use the \xab, \xbb buttons to select year\n' +
'- Use the \u2039 buttons to select month\n' +
'- Hold mouse button on any of the above buttons for faster selection.';
Calendar._TT["ABOUT_TIME"] = '\n\n' +
'Time selection:\n' +
'- Click on any of the time parts to increase it\n' +
'- or Shift-click to decrease it\n' +
'- or click and drag for faster selection.';

Calendar._TT["PREV_YEAR"] = 'Prev. year (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["PREV_MONTH"] = 'Prev. month (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["GO_TODAY"] = 'Go Today';
Calendar._TT["NEXT_MONTH"] = 'Next month (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["NEXT_YEAR"] = 'Next year (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["SEL_DATE"] = 'Select date';
Calendar._TT["DRAG_TO_MOVE"] = 'Drag to move';
Calendar._TT["PART_TODAY"] = ' (' + "today" + ')';

// the following is to inform that "%s" is to be the first day of week
Calendar._TT["DAY_FIRST"] = 'Display %s first';

// This may be locale-dependent. It specifies the week-end days, as an array
// of comma-separated numbers. The numbers are from 0 to 6: 0 means Sunday, 1
// means Monday, etc.
Calendar._TT["WEEKEND"] = "0,6";

Calendar._TT["CLOSE"] = 'Close';
Calendar._TT["TODAY"] = "today";
Calendar._TT["TIME_PART"] = '(Shift-)Click or drag to change value';

// date formats
Calendar._TT["DEF_DATE_FORMAT"] = "%b %e, %Y";
Calendar._TT["TT_DATE_FORMAT"] = "%B %e, %Y";

Calendar._TT["WK"] = "Week";
Calendar._TT["TIME"] = 'Time:';
//]]>
```

Is this needed for retail products? I never once seen a calendar on my site

Comment: This is use for date field if in ur page their no date field so no need of this js

Comment: What would be the best way to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar.js is use for date input for custom product options (during product creating in Admin add/edit product)

[image]

To remove the css from you header on your product detail page (Assuming that you don't have any custom product attribute that is of date input type).

Take a look at `catalog_product_view` /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

In your local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name></action>
      .....
```

See [Magento remove css or js from specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064604/magento-remove-css-or-js-from-specific-view)

To remove code from page

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product_options_wrapper">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>html_calendar</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

See [Magento - remove block using update XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937018/magento-remove-block-using-update-xml)